# MS OneNote on Mac OSX: Is it possible to export entire notebook to PDF?

Tags: macos, pdf, export, microsoft-onenote

The MS instructions I found for exporting an entire notebook to a PDF don't seem to apply on the Mac OSX version.  Is there a way to do this on Mac OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment, no! It is not possible. OneNote "is" / could be a fantastic program, but it does have a lot of critical limitations. A solution to your problem, which I also encountered, is to make an account for the office pack. You can do that through OneNote. Afterward, you will be able to share an online version of our entire notebook or open it at another PC or Mac.

Comment: Thanks.  Hmmm, so I could open it on a OC and then export it there?

Answer (score 7):

It is currently possible to *shift-select* all the pages you would like to export, *Copy* them, then *Paste* them into a Word document or something similar from which you can export to PDF or whatever format you prefer.

This is the only way I have found to export a hard-copy of multiple pages with OneNote Notebooks.

Comment: this worked for me.  Good workaround.

Comment: It works, but it is completely ridiculous, that one has to go over this

Answer (score 4):

Short answer - not on your Mac.

Workaround:

The easiest way to export an entire notebook as a PDF is to sync the notebook to a Microsoft account (if you're not already doing so). Then, find a Windows computer (libraries often have Windows computers with Microsoft products installed).

On a Windows computer, you'll be able to sync the notebook, and export it as a PDF. Make sure you're using the desktop version of OneNote and not the "tablet" version that you install from the windows application store.

It's ridiculous - but that's the easiest way to do it.