# I can't export my notebooks in onenote

Tags: microsoft-office, export, microsoft-onenote

I cannot seem to find a simple way to export my notebooks from the windows App (Downloaded from the Microsoft Store, not the Office 360 one).

When I read their documentation [on the support website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-and-import-onenote-notebooks-a4b60da5-8f33-464e-b1ba-b95ce540f309), I find this:

> Under My Notebooks, right-click (PC) or Control-click (Mac) the name
>   of the notebook that you want to export, and then click Export
>   notebook.
>
> On the screen that opens, click Export.
>
> Follow your browser's prompts to save the file in the location you
>   choose.

As I can't find anything in my OneDrive folder, I can only assume it's hidden somewhere on purpose.
Secondly, I can't seem to find this option in the context menu.

[image]

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/1213813/downloading-a-local-copy-of-one-note-from-office-365-online), while it seems like exactly my problem, doesn't solve it.
Any leads on how to do a local export? Also, how do I tell OneNote to save my data somewhere?

Comment: This is an App, which in modern parlance generally means you're dealing primarily with web content. You wanting it to be different has little to do with how MS has chosen to do this. Further, MS HAS offered a version of the product that has offline storage and such.

Comment: @music2myear but this solves none of the problems I'm facing..? What version of the app DID MS offer?

Comment: What we need to know is what specifically happened after you followed the steps in the document you say you followed, and what steps you've taken to troubleshoot. The MS documentation says you'll find the export option, but you jump over to saying you don't see anything in the OneNote directory. You also say you're looking on the web app version, but the documentation doesn't say anything about that version, so you haven't actually followed the steps in that document.